# Как сделать аккордион меню

Tags: jquery, css, css-animation, menu

Привет всем, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать аккордион меню под следующие условия:
1) Аккордион меню имеет 7 элементов (заголовок + текст, раскрывающийся)

```html
<div class="question_item col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Почему сокращение задолженности Доброкассой бесплатно для клиентов?
    </div>
    <p>
      Доброкасса является аккредитованным партнером многих федеральных банков. Согласно правилам деятельности портала, мы не берем никакой платы за оказанные услуги с наших клиентов, а все финансовые вопросы решаем с кредитными организациями.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Как это работает? 
    </div>
    <p>
      После подписания договора и проведенных переговоров с кредитной организацией, Доброкасса выкупает задолженность клиента. Из этой суммы долга клиент должен оплатить всего 15-25% в зависимости от тарифа. После погашения данной суммы остальные 75-85% задолженности списываются Доброкассой и клиенту предоставляется справка об отсутствии долга. При этом, размер сокращения долга согласовывается с клиентом заранее и фиксируется в договоре. Также клиент имеет возможность получить беспроцентную рассрочку и выплачивать остаток долга ежемесячно до 6 мес.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Чем Доброкасса отличается от юридических компаний?
    </div>
    <p>
      Мы стремимся быстро и безболезненно решать возникшие затруднения наших клиентов. В отличии от юридических компаний, мы не судимся с кредитной организацией, а наши клиенты не участвуют в длительных судебных разбирательствах. Мы стараемся договориться с кредиторами таким образом, чтобы в итоге довольными остались обе стороны, и клиент и кредитор. Доброкасса не берет с клиентов никаких комиссий, предоплат и абонентских платежей.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Как быстро проходит процедура уменьшения долга?
    </div>
    <p>
      В среднем процесс договоренности с кредитором, выкуп и уменьшение долга занимает не более 90 дней. За это время наша команда проводит большой объем работы. Текущий статус процесса клиент может видеть в своем личном кабинете.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Может ли Доброкасса одновременно сократить задолженность перед несколькими банками или кредиторами?
    </div>
    <p>
      Доброкасса позволяет объединить и уменьшить несколько кредитов клиентов. При этом долги могут быть как перед банками так и перед микрофинансовыми организациями.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      Как узнать, что задолженность уменьшена и действительно закрыта?
    </div>
    <p>
      После подписания договора с Доброкассой, клиент может обратиться в свою кредитную организацию за уточнением статуса долга. В большинстве случаев уже на следующий день после сделки, предыдущий кредитор не будет иметь никаких претензий к клиенту.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="question_title">
      В каких случаях возможно обратиться в Доброкассу?
    </div>
    <p>
      В случае если клиент в силу сложившихся обстоятельств не имеет возможности в полном объёме исполнять свои обязательства перед кредиторами и просрочка составляет более 90 дней. При этом сокращение задолженности и предоставление беспроцентной рассрочки позволяет клиенту уложиться в его ежемесячный бюджет и комфортно выплатить остаток долга.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) При клике на один элемент, текст разворачивается, при этом тексты в других элементах должны сворачиваться

3) При клике на раскрытый элемент он тоже должен сворачиваться

```
$('.question_item > .content > .question_title').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this),
        $data = $this.next();

    $this.closest('.question_item').find('.content p:visible').not($data).slideUp(300);
    $data.slideToggle(300).toggleClass('is_active');;

});
```

Comment: Это не фриланс биржа. Вы же даже не попытались ничего сделать!
есть уйма готовых плагинов, стоит только поискать. Как и кастомные, вполне можно найти. Например себе такой делала http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/JRmQZo?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так это делается, за основу взят обычный  [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav > ul > li > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
      $data = $this.next();
    $this.closest('.nav').find('ul ul:visible').not($data).slideUp();
    $data.slideToggle();
  });
})
```

```css
.nav {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
}
.nav ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
}
.nav ul li ul li a {
  background: #eee;
}
.nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Компьютерная техника</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Компьютеры</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Ноутбуки</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Планшеты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Бытовая техника</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Крупная</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Средняя</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Мелкая</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Телефоны</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Мобильные</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Стационарные</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
```